# Is my pointer bad initialized?

Tags: c, pointers

I am struggling with an error while debugging my application, I have been able to point out that the error seems to happen in the call to the function *adc_gain_enum_to_real_gain()*,however I don't see why it goes wrong, I suspect is related to passing/reading the pointer `&adc_gain`. Any hints?

Thanks in advance!

```
void saadc_handler_interrupt(nrf_drv_saadc_evt_t const * const p_event)
{
    uint32_t err_code;
    uint16_t voltage;
    nrf_saadc_value_t adc_result;
    uint16_t tmp_voltage;
    float    adc_gain;

    if (p_event->type == NRF_DRV_SAADC_EVT_CALIBRATEDONE)
    {
        m_adc_cal_in_progress = false;
    }
    else if (p_event->type == NRF_DRV_SAADC_EVT_DONE)
    {
        adc_result = p_event->data.done.p_buffer[0];
        err_code = nrf_drv_saadc_buffer_convert(p_event->data.done.p_buffer, 1);
        APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);

        err_code = adc_gain_enum_to_real_gain(ADC_GAIN, &adc_gain); //<===HERE!!
        APP_ERROR_CHECK(err_code);

        float tmp =  adc_result / (( (1/6)  / ADC_REFERENCE_VOLTAGE) * pow(2, ADC_RESOLUTION_BITS));
        tmp_voltage =  (uint16_t) ((tmp / m_battery_divider_factor) * 1000);
        voltage = ( (tmp_voltage + 5) / 10) * 10;  // Round the value.

        NRF_LOG_INFO("Read value from saadc %d\nV",voltage);
        batt_event_handler_adc(voltage);
    }

    //nrf_drv_saadc_uninit();
}
```

Such a function is

```
uint32_t adc_gain_enum_to_real_gain(nrf_saadc_gain_t gain_reg, float * const real_val)
{
    switch(gain_reg)
    {
        case NRF_SAADC_GAIN1_6: *real_val = 1 / (float)6;
        break;
        case NRF_SAADC_GAIN1_5: *real_val = 1 / (float)5;
        break;
        case NRF_SAADC_GAIN1_4: *real_val = 1 / (float)4;
        break;
        case NRF_SAADC_GAIN1_3: *real_val = 1 / (float)3;
        break;
        case NRF_SAADC_GAIN1_2: *real_val = 1 / (float)2;
        break;
        case NRF_SAADC_GAIN1:   *real_val = 1;
        break;
        case NRF_SAADC_GAIN2:   *real_val = 2;
        break;
        case NRF_SAADC_GAIN4:   *real_val = 3;
        break;
        default: return M_BATT_STATUS_CODE_INVALID_PARAM;
    };

    return M_BATT_STATUS_CODE_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Quote the error message verbatim and identify the line it occurs in, please.

Comment: [MCVE] please..

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: What is the error? is it syntax error, or logical error?

Comment: '&adc_gain' looks OK to me - it's just the address of a local.  'ADC_GAIN' looks more suspicoius to me.  You do not show the type 'nrf_saadc_gain_t' or any debug that shows that the argument is valid.  What is  'ADC_GAIN' and is it valid?  What happens when you single-step though 'adc_gain_enum_to_real_gain' ?

Comment: OK, it's an enum, and there is a default catch in the switch, so prolly OK-ish as it stands..

Comment: What is ADC_GAIN {macro}? No issues with &adc_gain() and adc_gain_enum_to_real_gain function definition

Comment: Just a thought - is the FP library reentrant, 'cos you're calling it from an interrupt?  If FP absolutely necessary in this interupt handler?

Comment: Really, since this is an interrupt driver and involves hardware, it's imp..'very difficult' for us to reproduce, and we're reduced to guessing.  You really need to be into this with your own debugger on your own hardware;(

Comment: @MartinJames I don't get any error, the program goes to the appliclation error that is generic and it doesn't show anything ADC_GAIN is defined as this.`#define ADC_GAIN                    NRF_SAADC_GAIN1     // ADC gain.`

Comment: You can't use floats in interrupt routines because the interrupt mechanism does not save the floating point state.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
          float tmp =  adc_result / (( (1/6)  / ADC_REFERENCE_VOLTAGE) * pow(2, ADC_RESOLUTION_BITS));
```

`(1/6)` will always evaluate to `0`. It's an integer division!

So the whole expression `(( (1/6)  / ADC_REFERENCE_VOLTAGE) * pow(2, ADC_RESOLUTION_BITS))` results in `0.` (note: floating point here), which in turn provokes a division by zero here `adc_result / ...`.

To fix this either do

```
(1./6)
```

or

```
(1/6.)
```

or

```
((float) 1/6)
```

or

```
(1 /(float) 6)
```

or any combination of the above.

---

Unrelated but another cause of trouble related to integer division as well is here:

```
  (tmp_voltage + 5) / 10
```

Fix as above.